# Excel formula producing #VALUE! even though I have all numbers

Tags: excel

Why isn't this formula working:

```
=IF(C2:N2>1,SUM(C2:N2-1),SUM(C2:N2))
```

There are no spaces, all are numbers in that range. Yet it produces the dreaded #VALUE! error. I've looked up everything and tried every possible way of doing this. I tried sumif but I can't take 1 off the cell value in that, it seems.

What I'm trying to do: If the number in the cell is larger than 1, then sum each number -1 off it.

Comment: the issue is this part: `SUM(C2:N2-1)` and this `C2:N2>1`, what exactly do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The firrst argument works fine, if you would enter it as an array formula.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost You just answered his question.  Why don't you go ahead and post?

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula.

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A3>1,(A1:A3)-1,A1:A3))
```

[image]

Note: Press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` after typing formula.